# Trying to delete duplicates in char array/cstring?

Tags: c++, cstring, character-arrays

I don't understand why my code isn't working. The commented out code would remove the wrong characters and not remove any spaces, but the current delete_repeats function is giving me an error of: `line 49: expected initializer before numeric constant.

Can anyone help me?`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void fill_array(char a[], int size, int& number_used);
void delete_repeats(char a[], int& number_used);
void sentences_output(char a[], int& number_used);

int main()
{
    char sentences[100];
    int used=0;
    fill_array(sentences, 100, used);
    delete_repeats(sentences, used);
    sentences_output(sentences, used);
    return 0;
}

void fill_array(char a[], int size, int& number_used)
{
    char c;
    int index = 0;
    cout<<"Enter your sentence or sentences and press enter. \n"
        << "The max number of characters is 100.\n";
    cin.get(c);
    while((c != '\n')&&(index < size))
    {
        a[index]=c;
        cin.get(c);
        index++;
    }
    number_used = index;
    cout<<"Your original array size was "<<number_used<<endl;
    return;
}
void delete_repeats(char a[], int& number_used)
48{
        int counter = number_used;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_used; i++)
        {

            for (int j = i+1; j < number_used; j++) 
            {
                if (a[i] == a[j])
                {

                    for (int k = j; k < number_used - 1; k++) 
                    {

                        a[k]= a[k + 1];
                    }
      //      }  wrong place; j-- and size-- only if a duplicate
                  j--;
                  number_used--;
                } // moved brace here
                cout << "size = " << number_used;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    return;
    }
/*
void delete_repeats(char a[], int& number_used)
{
    int location = 0;
    int target = 0;
    int change;

    for(location = 0; location < number_used; location++)
    {

        for(target = 0; target<number_used; target++)
        {
            change = target;
            if(a[location] == a[target])
            {
                a[target] = a[change+(target - location)];
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
*/
void sentences_output(char a[], int& number_used)
{
    cout<<"The new sentence is \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < number_used; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;

    }
    cout<<"The size of the new array is \n";
    cout<<number_used<<endl;
    return;
}
```

The commented out delete_repeats was the second one I came up with and the first delete_repeats was from an example I found, but neither is working.

Thanks everyone! Here is my corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void fill_array(char a[], int size, int& number_used);
void delete_repeats(char a[], int& number_used);
void sentences_output(char a[], int& number_used);

int main()
{
    char sentences[100];
    int used=0;
    fill_array(sentences, 100, used);
    delete_repeats(sentences, used);
    sentences_output(sentences, used);
    return 0;
}

void fill_array(char a[], int size, int& number_used)
{
    char c;
    int index = 0;
    cout<<"Enter your sentence or sentences and press enter. \n"
        << "The max number of characters is 100.\n";
    cin.get(c);
    while((c != '\n')&&(index < size))
    {
        a[index]=c;
        cin.get(c);
        index++;
    }
    number_used = index;
    cout<<"Your original array size was "<<number_used<<endl;
    return;
}
void delete_repeats(char a[], int& number_used)
{
    int counter = number_used;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_used; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < number_used; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < number_used - 1; k++)
                {
                    a[k]= a[k + 1];
                }
                j--;
                number_used--;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

void sentences_output(char a[], int& number_used)
{
    cout<<"The new sentence is \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < number_used; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    }
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"The size of the new array is \n";
    cout<<number_used<<endl;
    return;
}
```

I removed the commented out delete_repeats function and edited the new one as well as changed the output function.

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::string` for the input but a `char[]`? Is it an exercise?

Comment: SO doesn't display line numbers. When quoting error messages, show whole error and tell us which line it corresponds to.

Comment: Yeah, this is an exercise and I've been working on it and three other programs all night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the line numbers in your actual code!?  That would give the error you quote.

Comment: yeah I did, thanks, I fixed that.